# Zend Framework 1.12 - Zend Command Line PHP deprecated

Tags: zend-framework

I use  local server - "WebServ", directory : "**D:\Program Files\WebServ\php**".

My directory to Zend library: "**D:\Library\ZendFramework**".

I add path to bin folder of zend and path to php.ini file 
Variable Path - "**D:\Program Files\WebServ\php;**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\;D:\Library\Android SDK\sdk\tools\;D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;**D:\Library\ZendFramework\bin**"

Now when I insert into comand line (in Windows):
**zf show version**

I have output:

```
C:\Users\Mati>zf show version
PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

Deprecated: Directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  require_once(Zend/Config/Ini.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
 D:\Library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Config.php on line 90

Warning: require_once(Zend/Config/Ini.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Config.php on line 90
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Config/Ini.php' (include_path='.;c:\
php\includes;D:\Library\ZendFramework\library;D:\Biblioteki\ZendFramework\extras\library') in D:\Library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Config.php on line 90

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Config/Ini.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes;D:\Library\ZendFramework\library;D:\Biblioteki\ZendFramework\extras\library') in D:\Library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Config.php on line 90
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here: one is that your server php configuration uses flag register_globals which is deprecated. Not sure if you need it but better to turn it off for security reasons. You can turn it off in your php.ini

Second error is php can't find file. I'm not a Win user, so I can't really help you but I would check is it ok to have spaces in include_path and also try path withou "**" in it. And ofcource just to be 100% proof make sure that file is there.